# Printer Idle status in Ubuntu 64bit with Canon LBP6000

Tags: printing, canon

Another Canon printer problem with Ubuntu. I have installed my Canon LBP6000 in Ubuntu using several tutorials of different web sites. Here is the property page of my printer.

[image]

When I print any document it says it is printing and after some seconds it says printing is completed. But it doesn't print anything at all. I think something is wrong with it, but don't know what. I have been trying to manage it during 3 months but without any success. Could anybody help me to configure my printer so that I could use it in Ubuntu please? If any further information needed I can provide it without any problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't configure Canon LBP2900b printer in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303064/cant-configure-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-20-04)

Comment: sudo systemctl restart cups

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands after turning on the machine,

```
sudo pkill -9 -x ccpd
sudo pkill -9 -x captmoncnabc
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
/etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

If it still does not print, try turning off and on the printer once.