# Can't configure Canon LBP2900b printer in 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I cannot configure my Canon lbp2900b printer in Ubuntu 20.04. I have a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04, and it is working fine in Windows 10. When I turn on the printer in Ubuntu it is showing `Configuring printer please wait...` and after some time it is showing `Printer added Canon lbp2900`, but when I print a test page it's showing `Printing test page` and then it is showing `Printing completed` but there is no response from the printer.

I installed the driver for linux_64 from the official Canon website.

Results of `lpinfo -v` :

```
file cups-brf:/
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
network https
network beh
direct ccp
direct hp
network ipps
network http
network ipp
network socket
network lpd
direct hpfax
```

and the command `systemctl list-units "ippusbxd" | grep service` shows nothing.

Comment: Please provide the outputs from `lpinfo -v` and `systemctl list-units "ippusbxd" | grep service`.

Comment: @brian_p    I have added the results in the edit

Comment: `lpinfo -v` does not show an entry (a URI) for the ccp line.  This is what should be used for  the `-v` option in the answer from @pLumo. A URI is where the print job is sent to. No such destination appears to exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The printer unfortunately does not work out of the box, you need to manually install some dependencies and then add it as "Canon Capt" source.

---

**There is a fully automated installation script**:

--> https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer

---

If you prefer a manual installation, here are the ...

**Basic steps for manual installation:**

- Install the Debian/64bit drivers from the canon webpage
- Enable multiarch

  ```
  dpkg --add-architecture i386
  ```
- Install 32-bit dependencies

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpopt0:i386
  ```
- Add the printer:

  ```
  lpadmin -p LBP2900b -m /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP2900BCAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687
  ccpdadmin -p LBP200b -o /dev/usb/lp0
  ```

Adjust the path to the `ppd`-file if necessary.

---

See also:

- [Similar question on askubuntu for 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04/464334).
- [This page on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) for more, but outdated information.

Comment: It worked !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much :))))