# CANON LBP6200d driver problem

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

My printer works just fine in Windows 10 but in Ubuntu when I downloaded the printer drivers for linux 64 bit from [the Canon website](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp6200d.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux) and downloaded them like this [PIC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlDSM.png)

[PIC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqWiR.png)

But then when I print, a message appears

> Document is printing

And then another message says

> Print is completed

But the printer hasn't even printed a single page.

Someone please tell me how to solve problem and note that I am new to Linux so if I am asking something dumb please don't ignore that dumb thing.

Comment: You should check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303064/cant-configure-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-20-04). That should also work the same for LBP6200d, at least it's in the scripts list of supported models.