# Missing print filter for LBP2900

Tags: 20.04, printing

I run Windows 7 and Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. I connect my printer LBP2900 through USB whenever I want to print, else I keep it disconnected. After finding solution online, I was able to print. Currently it doesn't print when I give print command. After going through setting, I read "There is a missing print filter for 'LBP2900'." How to get my printer working?

Comment: Have you tried adding the printer in the Settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't configure Canon LBP2900b printer in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303064/cant-configure-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-20-04)

Comment: Initially I went through that link and got my printer working, but this link installed 'cndrvcups-capt' package which blocked update on my laptop. I even could not install any other package due to this. Finally I had to remove it.